# Return a list of all the even elements in the orginal list - how can I write this function without using recursion?

Tags: sml

This function takes a list and returns a list of all the even elements from the original list. I'm trying to figure out how to do this using `foldl`, `foldr`, or `map` instead but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
fun evens [] = []
    | evens (x::xs) =
        if
            x mod 2 = 0
        then
            x::evens(xs)
        else
            evens(xs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want fewer elements than you start with, `map` is out.
If you copy a list using both `foldl` and `foldr`,

```
- foldl (op ::) [] [1,2,3];
val it = [3,2,1] : int list

- foldr (op ::) [] [1,2,3];
val it = [1,2,3] : int list
```

you see that `foldl` reverses it, so `foldr` is a pretty natural choice if you want to maintain the order.

Now all you need is a function that conses a number to a list if it is even, and just produces the list otherwise.
Like this one:

```
fun cons_if_even (x, xs) = if x mod 2 = 0 then x::xs else xs
```

And then you have

```
fun evens xs = foldr cons_if_even [] xs
```

or inlined,

```
fun evens xs = foldr (fn (y, ys) => if y mod 2 = 0 then y::ys else ys) [] xs
```

It's more "natural" to use the standard filtering function, though:

```
fun evens xs = filter (fn x => x mod 2 = 0) xs
```